# Need free time slots from total time

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

There is one pitch and pitch has its own start time and end time (e.g from `8:00 AM` to `7:00 PM`). And multiple matches has already been scheduled on pitch with some time. (e.g from `8:30AM` to `9:00AM`, `10:00 AM` to `10:30 AM`) So now what i want to calculate is available time on pitch. My code is here:

```
$pitchStart = '2018-06-11 08:00 AM';
$pitchClose = '2018-06-11 09:00 PM';

$firstGameStart = '2018-06-11 09:30 AM';
$firstGameEnd = '2018-06-11 10:00 AM';

$secondGameStart = '2018-06-11 10:00 AM';
$secondGameEnd = '2018-06-11 10:30 AM';

$thirdGameStart = '2018-06-11 11:00 AM';
$thirdGameEnd = '2018-06-11 11:30 AM';


$Result = [
    [0] => ['freeSlotStart' => '2018-06-11 08:00 AM','freeSlotEnd' => '2018-06-11 09:30 AM'],
    [1] => ['freeSlotStart' => '2018-06-11 10:30 AM','freeSlotEnd' => '2018-06-11 11:00 AM'],
    [2] => ['freeSlotStart' => '2018-06-11 11:30 AM','freeSlotEnd' => '2018-06-11 09:00 PM'],
];
```

Comment: I think the bit of code in the middle is missing. Can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: Actually i just need logic (Ways) to implement above one. And sorry to say but i cant share the code because it includes too many other things and code is very longer too. @KIKOSoftware

Comment: The most basic algorithm would be this: 1. sort all the times you have. 2. the first time tells you when the pitch opens, so that's a start of a free slot. 3. the next time tells you the start of the first game, so that's a end of a free slot. 4. continue to consume start and finish times of free slot until the end. Finally: This is based on the assumption that no overlapping games have been planned.

Answer (score 0):

The pitch is free:

1. In between games.
2. Between `opening time of the pitch` and `start of the first game`.
3. Between `end of the last game` and `closing time of the pitch`.

If you'd store the games in array instead of variables, you can simply determine the times for the above cases -- if applicable -- by looping over the array.

---

Something along these lines may work:

```
<?php
$pitchOpeningTimes =
    [
        'pitchStart' => '2018-06-11 08:00 AM',
        'pitchClose' => '2018-06-11 09:00 PM'
    ];

$games = [
    [
        'GameStart' => '2018-06-11 09:30 AM',
        'GameEnd' => '2018-06-11 10:00 AM',
    ],
    [
        'GameStart' => '2018-06-11 10:00 AM',
        'GameEnd' => '2018-06-11 10:30 AM',
    ],
    [
        'GameStart' => '2018-06-11 11:00 AM',
        'GameEnd' => '2018-06-11 11:30 AM',
    ]
]; // Assuming these are sorted ascending, if this assumption is wrong, sort it.

function openSlots($openingTimes, $plannedGames)
{
    if (count($plannedGames) == 0) { # No games planned, pitch is free all day.
        return ['freeSlotStart' => $openingTimes['pitchStart'], 'freeSlotEnd' => $openingTimes['pitchClose']];
    }

    $freeslots = []; # We need a result array to push our free slots to.

    // First edge case: pitch might be free between pitchStart and start of the first game
    // if game doesn't start at opening of the pitch.
    if ($plannedGames[0]['GameStart'] !== $openingTimes['pitchStart']) {
        $freeslots[] = [
            'freeSlotStart' => $openingTimes['pitchStart'],
            'freeSlotEnd' => $plannedGames[0]['GameStart']
        ];
    }

    // Loop over the games to check for open slots between games.
    for ($g = 0; $g < count($plannedGames) - 1; $g++) {
        if ($plannedGames[$g]['GameEnd'] !== $plannedGames[$g + 1]['GameStart']) {
            // echo $g;
            $freeslots[] = [
                'freeSlotStart' => $plannedGames[$g]['GameEnd'],
                'freeSlotEnd' => $plannedGames[$g + 1]['GameStart']
            ];
        }
    }

    // Second edge case: pitch might be free between pitchEnd and end of the last game
    // If game doesn't end at the time the pitch closes.
    $lastGame = end($plannedGames);
    if ($lastGame['GameEnd'] !== $openingTimes['pitchClose']) {
        $freeslots[] = [
            'freeSlotStart' => $lastGame['GameEnd'],
            'freeSlotEnd' => $openingTimes['pitchClose']
        ];
    }

    return $freeslots;
}

var_dump(openSlots($pitchOpeningTimes, $games));
```

**Note:**

1. Comparing datetimes as strings (probably) isn't best practice.
2. The above code isn't very elegant.
3. I haven't tested this code to output the desired results. At least it should be a good hint in the right direction.

---

### Edit:

After your *your code is not working* comment, I took about 10 seconds of my time to:

1. Add `echo $g;` to the for loop.
2. Notice that the for-loop wasn't executing.
3. Notice the the fact that the increment and conditional were swapped around.

My code was working, in the sense -- as I stated -- that it was merely an attempt to push you in the right direction. I strongly feel that it shouldn't have been my time, but yours, that was spent on this quick fix. Anyway, enough with the tirade, I've changed: `for ($g = 0; $g++; $g < count($plannedGames) - 1)` to `for ($g = 0; $g < count($plannedGames) - 1; $g++)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Niellles, I have tried this above code but it returns only 
 - Time between pitchStart and start of the first game
 - Time between pitchEnd and end of the last game

But it is not returning time between games.

Thanks

Comment: @SunnySheth On behalf of future readers; thanks for accepting the answer!

Comment: Hi @Nielles, I'm facing one more issue if you can help out please.
Here we are expecting only one pitch start time and close time.
`$pitchOpeningTimes =
    [
        'pitchStart' => '2018-06-11 08:00 AM',
        'pitchClose' => '2018-06-11 09:00 PM'
    ];`
But in my case there are multiple pitch start time and end time.

For e.g
$pitchOpeningTimes = [
    [
        'pitchStart' => '2018-06-11 08:00 AM',
        'pitchClose' => '2018-06-11 09:00 PM'
    ], 
    [
        'pitchStart' => '2018-06-11 12:00 AM',
        'pitchClose' => '2018-06-11 03:00 PM'
    ],
]

Comment: @SunnySheth This addition is outside the scope of your original question and should be a new question. That is if, after some attempts made by yourself, you can't figure it out. Something in the direction of: `foreach ($pitchOpeningTimes as $pitch => $times) { $openSlots[$pitch] = openingTimes($times, $games);}` would work. Although this wouldn't work as is, since there's no distinction in the `$games` array as to which game is played on which pitch.